# Question about select all H3 inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wouldn't this work if I want to apply a new class to all H3 tags inside the RelArtik div?

```
$("h3",$("#RelArtik")).addClass("underrubrik");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) jQuery *should* accept a jQuery object as the context so there's no obvious reason why what you've written shouldn't work.

However, it also says that:

```
$(selector, context)
```

is equivalent to:

```
$(context).find(selector)
```

So you could just try:

```
$('#RelArtik').find('h3').addClass(...);
```

which is of course also equivalent to:

```
$('#RelArtik h3').addClass(...);
```

however I believe the former `.find()` based solution is faster.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to select another class from another stylesheet? A stylesheet that isn't in the HEAD tag from the beginning?

Comment: @user790843 it's certainly possible to have JS load new CSS files, and then use those styles, but I've never tried it myself.

Answer (score 3):

it's the same as CSS and would work with a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$("#RelArtik h3").addClass("underrubrik");
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can just do:

```
$('#RelArtik h3').addClass('underrubrik');
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw that while I posted this answer someone else already gave the same answer...